# How to update tcpdump?

Tags: centos, tcpdump

I would like to update `tcpdump` on my computer (CentOS 6.5) which is currently old. I download the zip file from TCPDUMP/LIBPCAP public repository already but I don't know how to update with this file.

Do I have to delete `tcpdump` on my computer first? Would you please provide the step for me?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, `tcpdump` will be in the yum repositories.

A simple `sudo yum install tcpdump` should get you up to date with the latest version available in the repositories.

Since you are a newbie on Linux, I would recommend doing everything through your package manager and not installing software outside of the package manager. It will make your life easier if everything is done through `yum`

Comment: I did but I want the latest version of tcpdump that is 4.6.1 instead of 4.0 that come from yum command.

Comment: Why do you want the absolute latest version ? Is the one from yum missing some functionality that you need ?

Comment: because Snort require it as told in [link]https://www.snort.org/documents/4
on the second paragraph in a second page

Answer (score 0):

You may find a more recent version of `tcpdump` in the [CentOS additional repositories](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories):

> There are several repositories provided by CentOS and other 3rd party
>   developers that offer software packages that are not included in the
>   default base and updates repositories. While no list can be 100%
>   complete, as anyone may announce an archive, it represents some major
>   efforts and provides a summary of what each repository offers. These
>   repositories have **varying levels of stability, support and cooperation**
>   within the CentOS community.

If you really want the latest `tcpdump` version, you will need to compile `tcpdump` and `libpcap` from the sources you downloaded. You need to unzip the archives and follow instructions given in the INSTALL.txt file (starting with `libpcap` because it is a dependency of `tcpdump`)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use the latest tcpdump from http://www.tcpdump.org/#latest-releases , you'll probably won't find any binary rpm ready to install.

However, it's very easy to build it on your system, if you have or can install build tools (you'll need at least gcc, make, autoconf I think). 
In such case, you can have your private copy of tcpdump (new relaease) while keeping official rpm unchanged. 
If so, once you have gcc, make, autoconf installed with their dependencies:

- untar the tarballs you downloaded, for example in the directory where you downloaded the files:

     `$ tar zxf libpcap-1.8.1.tar.gz
     $ tar zxf tcpdump-4.9.1.tar.gz`
- build libpcap from sources:

     `$ cd libpcap-1.8.1 
     $ ./configure
     $ make`

This should complete with no error message, and you should find libpcap.a, libpcap.so.1.8.1 there.

- build tcpdump from sources: 

  `$ cd ../tcpdump-4.9.1
  $ ./configure
  $ make`

This should complete with no error message, and you should find tcpdump executable there.

Then you can put compiled binary file where you like (in your home directory, or elsewhere like /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib64...